# Translate interface (export/import)

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have two languages:

- french
- arabic

I want to completely translate the arabic interface. If there a way to export the englisch translations, add the arabic one and reimport the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using [Translation template extractor](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx) module

> If you are a translator, install the module on a Drupal site as you would with any other module. Once potx module is turned on, you can go to the "Extract strings" tab on the Locale administration interface, select the module or theme you want to have a translation template for, and submit the form. You will get one single template file generated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you! You need to completely translate the Arabic interface? Add the Arabic language to your website then simply, download it's translation  file and import it into `admin/config/regional/translate/import` . What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Completely translating the Drupal "interface" in another language is a bit bizarre/strange (as confirmed also by some of the other answers already). Therefor it may help to correctly understand the various Drupal components related to 'translation', as further explained below.

Drupal's translation system consists of 2 basic components: the translation of the **interface** and the translation of the **content** of a site.

The **translation of the interface** is about the translation of various text strings used throughout the site, like labels used on buttons such as submit, or on tabs such as view or edit. They are the same on all sites (no matter what actual content is contained in a site).

The **translation of the content** is about the translation of nodes and entities. It requires a place to actually store the translated versions of the content (in multiple languages) and a system to choose which content is to be displayed where. The systems available for translation of content are:

- **Content translation** (used in earlier versions of Drupal, and still available in D7), which translates entire nodes in multiple languages.
- **Entity translation** (its API was first introduced in Drupal version 7, though there is no UI for it yet), which translates fields attached to the same entity.

Typical (often used) modules related to translations:

- [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n).
- [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable).
- [Localization update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update).
- [Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation).

Modules to actually manage translations of nodes and/or entities:

- [Translation Management](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_management), for D6 only, not suited for D7.
- [Translation Overview](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_overview), for D7, mentioned as a recommended add-on by [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_management) also.
- [Translation Management Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt), for D7 and/or D8, considered as the successor of [Translation Overview](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_overview), and "the" module to move forward with in D8 also.